# Widget always in visible are in any height of window

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following situation, as you can see in pic, the widget block, must be always in visible are, but scroll from top edge to bottom edge during scrolling.

[image]

I set like this, but  when window is narrow , then because of scrool the widget goes under window.

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
  var $scrollingDiv = $(".widget");


          $scrollingDiv.css({
              "top": ($(window).scrollTop())
          });
```

});

How can I keep it between the edges during scrolling ?

[the jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/RbH9b/11/)

[live site example](http://www.ruazel.ru/?theme_preview=223986)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
var $scrollingDiv = $(".widget"),
    main = $('.main'),
    mainOff = main.offset().top,
    mainBottom = mainOff + main.height() - $scrollingDiv.height();
$(window).scroll(function () {
   var winScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(mainOff <= winScroll && winScroll <= mainBottom){
        $scrollingDiv.addClass('fixed').removeClass('bottom');
    }else if(winScroll > mainBottom){
        $scrollingDiv.addClass('bottom').removeClass('fixed');
    }
    else{
        $scrollingDiv.removeClass('fixed bottom')
    }

});
```

CSS:

```
.widget.fixed { position: fixed; left: auto; right: 50%; margin-right: -232px; }
.widget.bottom { top: auto; bottom: 0; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RbH9b/17/)

Pretty much I only add and remove classes, and making the element fixed in stead of adding new css every time there is scroll. That way the element won't jump and the site will work much better.

You can tweak it if you want the widget to stick at the bottom of the window instead of the top.

Comment: thank you for answer, but I need it (widget) to stay absolute to keep it exactly beside of ՝main՝ block

anyway thanks, I will try this one, if there is no any versions

Comment: But when you make it fixed with right: 50%; and push it with negative margin it will take the exact position as the absolute. The -135px is the value that you can change in order to put at the same spot that is when absolute. (in this case in the jsfiddle was -135px  in you case it will be bigger) As you see the widget stay absolute until the top reaches the main offset top, then I add class fixed in order ot fixed it.

Comment: in my monitor the fixed block here

https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-x-PhPK3G-W4/UsFzR-C85kI/AAAAAAAABN0/WoZngXqK9FA/s0/2013-12-30_17-20-46.png

Comment: Ok sry I thought it was self-explanatory. I centered the jsffddle example and edited the values. (that's how you live site looks and took in consideration that). Do you get it now ?

Comment: thank you, I add a bit transition and now it works great!

final result

http://jsfiddle.net/RbH9b/22/